# MySQL Alter table causes Error: Invalid use of NULL value

Tags: mysql

My existing table:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| creation_date   | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL                        |
```

I wanted to alter table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE enterprise MODIFY creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But I got this error:

ERROR 1138 (22004) at line 7: Invalid use of NULL value

The problem looks like from changing the Nullable which was YES to NOT NULL. Do I need to drop the column and add afterwards?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

It looks like there are few rows with NULL value.Update all null values to a default date in that column and then try to do a alter.

Try this

```
--update null value rows
UPDATE enterprise
SET creation_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE creation_date IS NULL;


ALTER TABLE enterprise 
MODIFY creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 11):

> You can't use this query until you have NO `NULL` values in the `creation_date`
>   column.

Update your `creation_date` column with some default date and then alter the table.

Like this

```
UPDATE enterprise SET creation_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE creation_date IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE enterprise MODIFY creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Late comment but I'm guessing that should be either you can't use as long as you have NULL values or until you haven't got any NULL values. Otherwise there wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, we can't change table structure if it is full with data.

Solving is:

1. delete all data in it by (`DELETE FROM table_name`) or update it by
   (`UPDATE table_name set new_value where condition`)
2. use (`ALTER` with `MODIFY` or `CHANGE`) to renew the structure of table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).